# How to use a custom syncing logic?

Tags: substrate-node, sync, network

I want to create a node with a different syncing logic than `SyncingEngine` (I have my own struct that implements the same API as `SyncingEngine`). To be clear, I want to use the substrate `NetworkService`

How can I do that? This is what I tried to do:

The function `build_network` in the client builds a `NetworkService` and spawns a thread that runs a `SyncingEngine`. I tried to copy it to my repo and change the usage of `SyncingEngine` with my own struct. The problem was that it uses private functions/structs (`build_network_future`, `build_system_rpc_future` and `TransactionPoolAdapter`)